# Angular 2 - Add animation handler directly on the selector

Tags: javascript, animation, angular

In all the angular 2 API animation examples, the animation handler is implemented on **innerHtml**,

I would like to put it directly on the component selector.

In the example below, `[@visibility]="visibility"` is on the `div` tag, but I want it on the `selector: 'vps-node'` so my template is simply `<ng-content>` with out the parent div tag

```
@Component({
selector: 'vps-node',
template: `<div [@visibility]="visibility"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`,
animations: [
    trigger('visibility', [
        state('in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
        transition('void => *', [
            animate(300, keyframes([
                style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)', offset: 0 }),
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(15px)', offset: 0.3 }),
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)', offset: 1.0 })
            ]))
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
            animate(300, keyframes([
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)', offset: 0 }),
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(-15px)', offset: 0.7 }),
                style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(100%)', offset: 1.0 })
            ]))
        ])
    ])
   ]
})
```

Comment: have you tried the `host` property on `@Component`? Like: `host : {'@visibility' : 'visibility'}` ?

Comment: yes, doesn't seem to trigger the animation unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Thought i'd share this but I have managed to make the animation trigger on the host element.

Check the following code where I handle page transitions.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'styles',
    templateUrl: './styles.template.html',
    host: {
        '(@routeAnimation.start)': 'pageEnterStarted($event)',
        '(@routeAnimation.done)': 'pageEnterCompleted($event)',
        '[@routeAnimation]': 'true',
    },
    animations: [
        trigger('routeAnimation', [
            state('*', style({ opacity: 1})),
            transition('void => *', [
                style({ opacity: 0}),
                animate(250)
            ]),
            transition('* => void', animate(250, style({opacity: 0})))
        ])
    ]
})
export class StylesComponent {
     pageEnterStarted() {
     }

     pageEnterCompleted() {
     }
}
```

Comment: got it working, see my answer. Thanks for the tips all!

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the host:property needed to be in a bracket.

host: { '**[** @visibility **]**': 'visibility' },

```
selector: 'vps-row-node',
host: { '[@visibility]': 'visibility' },
template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
animations: [...]
```